# why I only get a clearcase version 0?

Tags: clearcase

Normally, the first committed version should start from 1. Version 0 is identical with branch point. But now I got a only version 0, and this prevent me to checkin any other version coz it warned me that the branch already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in ["Before adding files and directories to source control"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/7.1.2?topic=control-before-adding-files-directories-source), the version 0 is a placeholder marking the start for all versions in a given branch:

[image]

You can end up with only the version 0 when you undo-checkout a file you just checked out in a new branch (in that case, only a version 0 for the newly created branch remains).

Regarding branches, you can have error like "`element already has a branch of type branch`", but only when there is an [issue with the server and client time (clock) being not in sync](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224441).

Comment: This is pretty much what I met, thanks. SCM team helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

ClearCase creates version 0 when you create an element (or a branch), which is usually checked out automatically. Version 0 is always either empty, or same as the branched version, as you noted. There shouldn't be any problem simply checking in version 1 on top of it.

Note that branches are created when you check out, not when you check in, so you shouldn't get any warnings on check-in. If you post the exact command line and warnings/errors, we'll probably be able to help you out more.

It could perhaps be that you've created a new element on your branch, and you're missing "/main/0 -mkbranch" in your config spec.

HTH.