# Finding all files with a specific version in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I want to find all files with a specific version in ClearCase. I did this:

```
cleartool find . -version 'version(<version-specifier>)' -print
```

This prints the fully qualified version of the files I am interested in, which is good. The problem with this is that it finds only files which are visible from the current view. For example, there is a file `some_directory/some_file`, and the version `<version-specifier>` (for exampe `/main/some_branch/LATEST` or `/SOME_LABEL`) exists for both `some_directory` and `some_file`. However, `some_file` does not exist in the current view (because the version of `some_directory` selected by the view does not contain that file). In this case, the above query doesn't find the file `some_file`.

Is there a way to find all files with the version `<version-specifier>`? To be more precise, it's good for me to find all files with the version `<version-specifier>` in any directory having the same version specifier? Is it possible without creating a new view or modifying the config spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by adding the `-nvis` option (from [`cleartool find` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)):

```
-nvi/sible
```

> Includes only those elements, along with their branches and versions, that are not visible (do not have a standard path name) in the view.

That can find elements which are no longer visible in the view you are using for your `cleartool find`.

The OP rightly comments:

> That only works only if I use `cleartool find -all` (then I don't even have to use `-nvisible`), but the problem with this is that it finds all files in the vob, not just ones based on the directory specified in the argument.

Making a dedicated view with the right config spec is the surest way to see and find what you want:

- first your specific selection rule,
- then more general ones (to be sure to select directories),
- finally `element * /main/LATEST`, which is a [selection rule stopper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12062472/6309).

Comment: That only works only if I use `cleartool find -all` (then I don't even have to use `-nvisible`), but the problem with this is that it finds all files in the vob not just ones based on the directory specified in the argument.

Comment: @petersohn in that case, making a dedicated view with the right config spec is the surest way: first your specific selection rule, then more general ones (to be sure to select directories, finally `element * /main/LATEST`.