# Getting error while check out the file

Tags: clearcase

Actually i created a view, branch and set the config secs for that view.
Its allowing to checkout the already existed files, but it does not allow to checkout the newly created files. its allow to create new elements by using "mkelem" command, but it does not allow to checkout that newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

For newly created file, you should see a rule like:

```
element * /main/0 -mkbranch newBrach
```

See for illustration "[Config spec rules for elements in subbranches](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_config_rules_subbranch.htm)":

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../bug-fix/LATEST
element * BASELINE-X -mkbranch bug-fix
element * /main/0 -mkbranch bug-fix
```

> Rule 4 (fourth line) determines that when a new element is created, the `mkbranch` clause causes the new element to be checked out on the bug-fix subbranch which is created automatically with the `mkbranch` command.
>   Also, if an existing element does not have a bug-fix branch or a version with the `BASELINE-X` label, the `bug-fix` branch is created when you check out the element.

So examine your config spec, and check if that `/main/0 -mkbranch` is there:

```
cleartool catcs -tag yourViewTag
```

See "[why I only get a clearcase version 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309333/why-i-only-get-a-clearcase-version-0/5309714#5309714)" for more on that "version 0", when an element is created.