# ClearCase: How to create branch with branch type

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm trying to use mkbranch command to create branch from main/abc branch.

I create branch type with following command:

```
mkbrtype –c "bugfix branch from abc" bugfixAbc
```

Now I need to create branch with that branch type.

How I'll create new branch from main/abc branch with branch type bugfixAbc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your config spec in order to create new versions starting from `abc`. see for example "[Where do new elements appear when `mkelem` is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071398/6309)":

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../bugfixAbc/LATEST
element * .../abc -mkbranch(bugfixAbc)
element * /main/0 -mkbranch(bugfixAbc)
element * /main/LATEST
```

The ellipsis `.../` in a selection rule allows for ClearCase to select that branch `abc`, from whatever branch it comes from: `/main`, or any other branch.

Using [`cleartool mkbranch`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbranch.htm) is not the solution here: it won't scale if you have to do it for many files, and it creates a version 0 left in checked-out state, that you should checkin. (or cancel the checkout, which would delete the branch)

By using a config spec, you will create automatically that branch each time you checkout an element present in the `abc` branch. Any element, not just a given file.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that I can give the path of the file like this:

```
mkbranch -c "bugfix branch from abc" bugfixAbc util.java@@/main/abc/27
```

So, this created branch from abc branch with branch type bugfixAbc

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain why mkbranch is not the solution here.

Comment: Another reason that you want to use the configspec option: If you manually run the mkbranch operation in a default configspec view, your changes will appear to vanish on chekin. They will still be there, but they won't be visible.