# ClearCase: How do I find which version I branched off from?

Tags: branch, clearcase

For a given file, say I branched off from `/main/2` and do my development in that branch `newBranch`. `cleartool diff -pred` would compare my loaded version (`/main/newBranch/LATEST`) to `/main/2`. Which clearcase command would I pass either the file name or `/main/newBranch` and would return `/main/2`?

I'm just trying to find which version `-pred` selects, but I can't find out how anywhere!

FOLLOW UP:
Say I checked the file in and now I'm in version `/main/newBranch/3`. How can I still compare it to where it was branched off from (`/main/2`)?

Answer (score 2):

Which ClearCase command would I pass either the file name or `/main/newBranch` and would return `/main/2`?

You can try using [`cleartool lsvtree`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-29&lang=en), which will list all versions of a file.

```
cleartool lsvtree myFile | grep main | head 1
```

As noted, [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-9&lang=en) is easier.

> How can I still compare it to where it was branched off from (`/main/2`)?

You can use the `/main/newBranch/0`, `0` being the [**placeholder** version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309714/6309) created for each new branch, here identical to `/main/2`, using [`cleartool diff`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-10&lang=en):

```
cleartool diff -pred yourFile yourFile@@/main/newBranch/0
```

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, `cleartool describe -short -pred <version0-of-child-branch>` did the trick. For my example, this would be `cleartool describe -short -pred /main/newBranch/0`.