# How to find files created by a user in all clearcase branches?

Tags: clearcase

I have to find files created by a particular user. But I need to query for all branches. How can i acheive this. I tried the below, it did not work.

cleartool find . -type f -ver "created_by(user)" -branch brtype(*) -print

Comment: Did yo try find -all? That would search in the all vob, not just the current view.

Comment: You wouldn't need the -branch in that case either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that "files created by a user" should mean "element", not version.

Looking for versions would give you any file a user has contributed to with a checkout/check-in, even though said user never "created" the file in the first place.

Creating a file should means adding an element to source control (and creating the version 0 of the branch `/main`, [placeholder for referencing that file, that new element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309714/6309))

Looking in all branches (actually, the all vob) is `cleartool find -all`

See "[Additional examples of the `cleartool find` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)"

For instance:

```
cleartool find -all -element "{created_by(user)}"
```

Would list all elements (file or directory) added to source control by a user.